# SwiftUI List with Section and Swipe Actions loads all rows at once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Consider the following code example (you can download it [here](https://easyupload.io/h2ix1r)):

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Row: View {

    var item: Item
    static var counter = 0

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item

        Row.counter += 1
        print(Row.counter)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items = (1...1000).map { Item(name: "Item \($0)") }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) {
                Row(item: $0)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        Button("Action", action: {})
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code prints out the numbers `1` to `21`, so around the amount of rows that are visible on the screen.

Now if I wrap the `ForEach` statement in a `Section`, the numbers `1` to `1000` are printed out. Hence, there is no cell reuse and all rows are loaded at once.

```
Section {
    ForEach(items) {
        Row(item: $0)
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                Button("Action", action: {})
            }
    }
}
```

If I remove the swipe action, the numbers `1` to `18` are printed out.

```
Section {
    ForEach(items) {
        Row(item: $0)
    }
}
```

Is this a known issue or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That probably is one of the inconsistent implementations in SwiftUI. I'd file a feedback to apple.

Comment: I started a thread on the apple dev forum. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716063

Comment: What happens if you put the Section in a List ?

Comment: @PtitXav the Section is part of the List

Comment: try to wrap your List content in another SwiftUI View file and use it from there, i noticed it works when smth goes wrong with views life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue even without the swipe action. I create a new SectionView for Lists with `.insetGroup` style until Apple fixes it. The downside is that the section header and footer are not equal to the original view.

It was tested and is working with iOS 15 and 16.

```swift
struct LazySection<Element, Row: View>: View where Element: Equatable, Element: Identifiable {

    // source: https://medium.com/devtechie/round-specific-corners-in-swiftui-d23ceee08188
    struct RoundedCorner: Shape {
        var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
        var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            return Path(path.cgPath)
        }
    }

    let elements: [Element]
    var header: String?
    var footer: String?
    @ViewBuilder let row: (_ element: Element) -> Row

    var body: some View {

        if let header = header {
            HeaderFooter(header, isHeader: true)
                .textCase(.uppercase)
        }

        if let first = elements.first,
           let last = elements.last {

            if first == last {
                row(first)
                    .listRowBackground(
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                            .clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 10))
                    )
            } else {
                row(first)
                    .listRowBackground(
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                            .clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 10, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]))
                    )
                ForEach(elements.dropFirst().dropLast()) { element in
                    row(element)
                }
                row(last)
                    .listRowBackground(
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                            .clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 10, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight]))
                    )
            }
        }

        if let footer = footer {
            HeaderFooter(footer, isHeader: false)
        }
    }

    func HeaderFooter(_ title: String, isHeader: Bool) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if isHeader == true {
                Spacer()
            }
            Text(title)
                .font(.footnote)
            if isHeader == false {
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.init(uiColor: .secondaryLabel))
        .listRowBackground(Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground))
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Using it with your given code example Item must conform to Equatable.

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Row: View {

    var item: Item
    static var counter = 0

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item

        Row.counter += 1
        print(Row.counter)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items = (1...1000).map { Item(name: "Item \($0)") }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            LazySection(elements: items) { element in
                Row(item: element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can createa  `LazyVStack` with a `ForEach` loop and style it as a List. Of course in this case you'll need to implement your own logic for deleting items. You can refer to this project where I replicated the Apple's List using a LazyVStack
https://github.com/MrRonanX/Test-Task.-List-Swipe-Actions

Comment: I checked that and replacing a plain list is working. But I noticed UX and UI differences, which isn't working for. I guess I will stick with my workaround for now

Answer (score -1):

## Concept:

- Don't worry about creation of Row instances, it is just a struct (stack allocation), it is not expensive.
- What is important is how many views are actually rendered, add a `onAppear { }`.
- Only 18 are printed for iPhone 14 pro (height)

## Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items = (1...1000).map { Item(name: "Item \($0)") }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Row(item: item)
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                            Button("Action", action: {})
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            print("name = \(item.name)")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

```
name = Item 18
name = Item 17
name = Item 16
name = Item 15
name = Item 14
name = Item 13
name = Item 12
name = Item 11
name = Item 10
name = Item 9
name = Item 8
name = Item 7
name = Item 6
name = Item 5
name = Item 4
name = Item 3
name = Item 2
name = Item 1
```

Comment: This is not solving this issue. Of course you just display roughly 18 items, but still all are allocated. I'm working on a bigger project which isn't just showing a Text. We have an overview screen of showing some information as list elements and each links to a detail screen. If you use a section all complex rows and it's even more complex detail view are allocated as well